# Proxy all subdomain to other domain path

Tags: nginx

How to proxy all subdomain to other domain path?

For example

```
SUBDOMAIN.abcxyz123.com
```

To be proxied to

```
myapp.otherdomain.com/SUBDOMAIN
```

Making sure that all header/path and query parameters in the request is kept.

Update:

I've tried and have a working config but still not the one I need:

```
server {
    listen  80;

    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.abcxyz123\.com$;

    location / {
    proxy_set_header Host "myapp.otherdomain.com";
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        # this worked:
        proxy_pass http://myapp.otherdomain.com/somepath/;
        # this does not work:
        #proxy_pass http://myapp.otherdomain.com/$subdomain$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: The rewrite directive shouldn't be slowing you down. I use rewrite in my config to keep the request params. Your proxy_pass has a given uri and i think it might cause some problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
server {
    server_name   ~^(?<subdomain>.*)\.abcxyz123\.com$;

    resolver 8.8.8.8;

    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /$subdomain/$1;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host "myapp.otherdomain.com";
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://myapp.otherdomain.com;
    }
}
```

This should proxy all your traffic with original query parameters(query strings, request body, request method, etc), I changed the host header to the proxied "myapp.otherdomain.com" incase the server of 'myapp.otherdomain.com' has more than one virtual hosts. If you don't want the change, use $host instead.

*This answer might need another edit since your question isn't very clear. If you have further question, comment and i will edit in my answer.*

Comment: @xybrek Sorry, i forget to correct a mistake in my server_name regex. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Anyway, after updating your code works for my app now. However its a bit slow? Is it because of the rewrite?

Comment: Perhaps you can also help with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37639189/nginx-proxy-too-slow